# Laravel: Stop using UUID as foreign key

Tags: laravel, uuid

Laravel is trying to use `uuid` field as foreign key. And I want to use foreign key with the field `id`. Is there any option there?

Using this trait on Model. And then it is trying to use the `uuid` as foreign key. But still I want to use `id` as foreign key.

```
<?php

namespace App\Library;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

trait UsesUuid
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKeyName()
    {
        return 'uuid';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }

    /**
     * @return false
     */
    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @param $uuid
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function scopeUuid($query, $uuid)
    {
        return $query->where($this->getUuidName(), $uuid);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUuidName()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'uuidName') ? $this->uuidName : 'uuid';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'uuidName') ? $this->uuidName : 'uuid';
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getUuidName()} = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @sta Already shared my trait to my question body.

Comment: How about override it ? or just put `protected $primaryKey = 'id'` on your model

Comment: I've tried in both way. Using `protected $primaryKey = 'id'` on model and also mentioning nothing on the model. If i not mention anything to the model, it should consider primary key as `id` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about this trait. You can make your own trait with id instead of uuid and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from methods `getIncrementing()` and `getKeyName()`. Laravel calls `getKeyName()` in amount of built-in functions to interacts with relationships, also other actions like `delete()`, route bindings, etc.

You should allow any models which uses this trait to custom the Primary key (PK), so that `uuid` is only common column at all.

Your trait definition is force PK column as `uuid`.

Below is my recommended for the trait

```php
<?php

namespace App\Library;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

trait UsesUuid
{
    /* Override this method to set `uuid` as PK */
    public function isUuidAsPrimaryKey()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKeyName()
    {
        return $this->isUuidAsPrimaryKey() ? $this->getUuidName() : $this->primaryKey;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return $this->isUuidAsPrimaryKey() ? 'string' : $this->keyType;
    }

    /**
     * @return false
     */
    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return !$this->isUuidAsPrimaryKey();
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @param $uuid
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function scopeUuid($query, $uuid)
    {
        return $query->where($this->getUuidName(), $uuid);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUuidName()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'uuidName') ? $this->uuidName : 'uuid';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'uuidName') ? $this->uuidName : 'uuid';
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getUuidName()} = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
        });
    }
}
```

If a model need to have `uuid` as PK, for example `Book` model

```php
class Book extends Model
{
    use UsesUuid;

    public function isUuidAsPrimaryKey()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Please recheck the method `isUuidAsPrimaryKey`. If it may not be overridden (due to conflict), then use a property instead.